# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ',' or ';' Error

Tags: php

I got this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ',' or
>   ';'.

What's the problem? I couldn't find it, Thanks.

```
echo '<strong>Role:</strong>'if($query['role'] == 1){echo 'Admin';} elseif ($query['role'] == 2){echo 'User'} '<br>';
```

Comment: After each expression in php you will need to have semicolon. After your ```echo``` statement you don't have semicolon ( ; ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '<strong>Role:</strong>';

if($query['role'] == 1){
    echo 'Admin';
} elseif ($query['role'] == 2){
    echo 'User';
} 

echo '<br>';
```